# How to filter a records having current date in it

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the records where the `file_name` column value contains the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format. For example if my table has:

```
abcd_2016-05-06.txt 
asd-2016-05-04.txt
axx_2016-05-03.txt
```

and I run the query on 2016-05-06, I want to only get `abcd_2016-05-06.txt` in the result set. How can I do that?

Comment: Huh?  No clue what you are asking.  Please show example table data, and queries, and expected output.

Comment: Is the date always in that format? Why does the title also refer to the time? This seems pretty simple but can you add more data and your expected result from that, along with any query attempts you have made and why they were wrong?

Comment: The file  name will be having  date (yyyy-MM-dd) format.i want to filter the records which is having current date in  it.

Comment: Select  filename from table where filename like '%2016-05-05%'. But here my constrain is i have to take the date from filename itself. The files which ia having current date in it.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the information you've been asked for. And also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to match the current date of the system, you could use the current date from the system. This works on Oracle, but other databases may have differing methods.

```
SELECT file_name
FROM MY_FILES
WHERE file_name LIKE '%' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'RRRR-MM-DD') || '.txt'
```

However, this is often a poor decision. It means that the code will never work for any date except the current system date. It would be much better to pass the date in as a parameter or get it from another table.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked for me..

Comment: @Midhun - If this works for you, please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Midhun - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). (Although I'm mildly curious why this answer works but mine doesn't; aside from this restricting you to .txt files - which wasn't a requirement - it's doing the same thing.)

Comment: @Midhun - that wasn't meant to suggest you should accept my answer over Liturgist's - it is entirely up to you, as the question asker, to decide which answer (if any) works best for you. I was just curious because you'd commented that this one worked.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Likewise, I was not implying that Midhun should choose mine over yours. When I saw his "it worked" message, I noticed that it was not marked as the answer. It is to everyone's benefit that answers are marked as such.

Comment: @Liturgist - absolutely, my link to the help center was just help the OP. as they are new I should have kept my curiosity quiet to avoid confusion. I don't care *which* answer is accepted *8-)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the current date to a string in the format you've shown with

```
to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

You can then concatenate that with wildcard characters to form a value like `'%2016-05-05%'`; and then find any values that are that match that wildcarded string, with [the `like` pattern-matching condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions007.htm):

```
select file_name    -- or count(*), or whatever columns you want
from your_table
where file_name like '%' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

The `like` operator paired with the `%` wildcard should help you.

```
select file_name 
from my_files
where file_name like '%2016-05-06%'
```

The query above `select`s all file names from the `my_files` `table` which contain the string enclosed between `'%` and `%'`.

If you get the number of such files, then you need something like this:

```
select count(*)
from my_files
where file_name like '%2016-05-06%'
```

Comment: I cant hard code the date. I wanted to filter The files which is having current date.

Comment: This is how you can get the current date: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm
If I were you, I would write a stored function for this purpose and would use the date to be checked as a parameter. That could be very useful on the long run.